# Vue loop not working when bootstrap-select is initialized

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, frontend, bootstrap-select

I have loop on my select dropdown by default it shows the data properly.

```
<select name="" id="input" class="form-control selectteam">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Filter by team</option>
    <option v-for="(team, index) in  nblTeams" :value="team.clubName">{{team.clubName}}</option>
</select>
```

but when I add **$('.selectteam').selectpicker();** in the mounted method as per code below

```
mounted: function() {
        this.getCurrentSeasonTeams().then( (response) => {
            if( response.status == 200 && typeof(response.data) == 'object' ) {
                this.nblTeams = response.data;
            }
        });

        $('.selectteam').selectpicker();
    }
```

it doesnt show the teams list already. Btw I'm using [bootstrap-select - Silvio Moreto](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Comment: How and where are you running the jQuery? Can you share that part of your code?

Comment: @ricopo I'm using a laravel 5.4. So I've required jQuery in my bootstrap.js and in Vue mounted method is where I'm initializing the bootstrap-select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue and I fixed that by adding ***setTimeout*** like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('.select-reviewer').selectpicker();
}, 10);
```

or this one if you've already initialized selectpicker:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('.select-reviewer').selectpicker('refresh');
}, 10);
```

Also I should mention about selected option. **Bootstrap-select removes any 'selected' attributes from  when it's initialized or refreshed** that's why here is the code which prevent this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('.select-reviewer').selectpicker('val', $('.select-reviewer option:selected').val());
}, delay);
```

As you see from the code above we just set the value in bootstrap-select when it's initialised.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using nextTick? init the bootstrapselect on the next tick of the vue clock

[VUE docs, next-tick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

**Example**

```
mounted: function() {
    this.getCurrentSeasonTeams().then( (response) => {
        if( response.status == 200 && typeof(response.data) == 'object' ) {
            this.nblTeams = response.data;
        }
    });

    this.$nextTick(function(){
        $('.selectteam').selectpicker();
    });
}
```

**EDIT :**

```
mounted: function() {
    this.getCurrentSeasonTeams().then( (response) => {
        if( response.status == 200 && typeof(response.data) == 'object' ) {
            this.nblTeams = response.data;

            this.$nextTick(function(){
              $('.selectteam').selectpicker();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: no console error @Taufik Akbar, I think I just solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

not really sure if what I've made is a good solution for my issue. Added a setTimeout method and it works.

```
    this.getCurrentSeasonTeams().then( (response) => {
        if( response.status == 200 && typeof(response.data) == 'object' ) {
            this.nblTeams = response.data;
            if(typeof(this.nblTeams) == 'object'){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('.team').selectpicker();
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @ricopo yes it needs the setTimeout to make it work, I think bootstrap-select checks the select box if it has options once the DOM is loaded, in my case maybe the loop is not yet finished rendering when I initialize bootstrap-select that's why select box has no options. Just a theory though

Comment: @PenAndPapers check my edit. your timeout method can fail if the list is longer

Comment: @TaufikAkbar yes I did, and I applied your solution, thanks